# Didn't get task/fetch query on bot after clicking from command box of ms teams app

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

[image]

As the above screenshot shows, got the error on clicking "Preview" button from command box.

"Preview" button is mapped to a "task/fetch" action, and is supposed to hit a request on bot /messages api. This functionality works as expected when the message is posted inside the conversation, but when the message is in the command box, the above error pops up.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample which you are referring to, so that we can repro it at our end?

Comment: By sample, you mean the manifest package for this app?

Comment: We mean documentation/Sample code repo links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We can not access the task module from the command box.